# Get a changelog of all changes since the next to last tag

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to figure out how to get a changelog of all of the changes since the next to last tag.

```
0.3                 //tag
did even more stuff //commit
did stuff           //commit
0.2                 //tag
...                 //commit(s)
0.1                 //tag
```

I want to get:

```
did even more stuff
did stuff
```

I tried this command from [here](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/08/03/shell-tricks-changelogs-with-git/), but it only got the commits since the last tag (not the next to last):

```
git log --pretty=format:"- %s%n%b" --since="$(git show -s --format=%ad `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)"
```

Comment: `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1` gets you the most recent tag. You need the two most recent tags and then to get the list from `tag-2..tag-1`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, I need to figure out how to get that second tag, was thinking `maxcount=2` and then convert to an array and get the second value. That wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: Actually, `rev-list --tags` isn't doing what you want here at all anyway. It isn't only selecting tags.

Comment: "Recent" doesn't really have that much meaning until you define it yourself.  For instance, suppose I mention that I have three branches and five tags: B1, B2, B3; T1, T2, T3, T4, T5.  Then I'll add that T5 is tagged to a commit that's reachable from both B1 and B3, but not B2; T1 is tagged to a commit reachable only from B2; and so on.  Once you define what you mean, there's probably a script-able solution...

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this can't be the right way to do this but this is what I've got at the moment.

This also assumes you want tags sorted by chronological date of commit (which may or may not be what you want... see torek's comment on the OP).

Use `git rev-parse --tags` to get just the tag refs.

Use `git rev-list --max-count=2 --no-walk --stdin` to get just the two "most recent" commits (``-no-walk` avoids getting anything not named explicitly).

Then use a bit of `sed` magic (`'x;n;s/$/../;G;s/\n//;p'`) to turn the revs we got into the desired selector.

```
$ git rev-parse --tags | git rev-list --max-count=2 --no-walk --stdin | sed -n 'x;n;s/$/../;G;s/\n//;p'
$ range=$(git rev-parse --tags | git rev-list --max-count=2 --no-walk --stdin | sed -n 'x;n;s/$/../;G;s/\n//;p')
$ git log --pretty=format:'- %s%n%b' "$range"
```

Alternatively, and I just thought of this you could probably also use something like this:

```
$ tag1=$(git describe --abbrev=0)
$ tag2=$(git describe --abbrev=0 "$tag1~")
$ git log --pretty=format:'- %s%n%b' "${tag1}..${tag2}"
```

Comment: I can't copy paste your examples because they include a $ on each line :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach based on `git log` (which walks the history backwards from a specified starting point, default `HEAD`) and `--decorate`:

```
git log --format='%H %d' | \
    awk '$2 ~ "tag:" { ntags++; } { if (ntags == 1) print $1 }'
```

This considers each reachable commit one at a time (as printed by `git log`, with %H printing the hash and %d adding branch and tag names that point to that commit).  The `awk` code then counts a commit as "tagged" if it has at least one tag, regardless of how *many* tags it has.  For all commits that are at-or-past the first tagged commit, but not yet at-or-past the second, it prints the hash.

Note that `git log` sorts commits by date, by default; you might want to restrict it to `--topo-order` depending on what you want.